# JavaScript full Object retrival inside from an object

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I have an object like the below. Now I want to get the object "window" only. How can I do it?

```
var jsonData = {

    "widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        },
        "image": { 
            "src": "Images/Sun.png",
            "name": "sun1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 250,
            "alignment": "center"
        },
        "text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "bold",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
var windowObj = jsonData.widget.window; //where data is your object
```

Comment: I would recommend not to use `window` as a variable name.

Comment: @Bergi -- Thanks for noticing that, answered without thinking :\

Answer (score 1):

```
var windowobj = jsonData.widget.window;
```

Note that if you are actually declaring your object literally like that, there is no JSON anywhere, so naming the variable `jsonData` is a bit strange.

Comment: why not json? the object pasted into a json parser parses just fine. if it's not json, why would the structure parse as JSON?

Comment: @dandavis Because JSON is a subset of Javascript object literal notation, which is what the OP is using (if it were all in a string, it would be JSON, which is why I said "if you are actually declaring your object literally like that"). If it comes from an AJAX request for xample, then it is JSON.